# How to log the messages to see them in MsBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, build, msbuild

I have a class, that inherits Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task. I am able to add a log by using Log.LogMessage() there and see it in MsBuild. However I call other classes inside Execute() and I want to be able to also add message log inside there. The other classes under Execute() don't inherit Task class as they are not a part of the tasks in the project. How can I add log message to other class to see the logs in MsBuild?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest three approaches.

1. Pass the [`TaskLoggingHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tasklogginghelper?view=msbuild-17-netcore) to your other class. The `Log` property of `Task` returns a `TaskLoggingHelper`. Pass the `TaskLoggingHelper` object to methods that need to log. A disadvantage is your other class would need to know about the `TaskLoggingHelper` type and would be coupled to the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities` namespace and the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` assembly.
2. Have your other class or the method of your other class log to a `StringBuilder`. When the method (or class) completes, construct a [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=net-7.0) with the built-up string from the `StringBuilder`. Pass the `StringReader` to the [`Log.LogMessagesFromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.tasklogginghelper.logmessagesfromstream?view=msbuild-17-netcore) method.
3. Have your other class provide `List<string>` collections for messages, warnings, and errors. Within the class or method, append to the appropriate collection. When the method or class completes, iterate each collection and call the appropriate method on the `Log`.

The best approach (or best combination of approaches) will vary with the details of the actual situation that you have.